# saving a folder from being destroyed after push on heroku

Tags: git, heroku, webserver

I have an app that lets users upload documents. The app saves the documents to a folder on the server, say users_documents. The app is hosted on Heroku.

When I do a git push heroku master the new app is deployed but all the files in users_documents are deleted, is there a way to tell git (or heroku) not to rewrite that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be storing your data in something more permanent than [Heroku's ephemeral file storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-isolation#ephemeral_filesystem). When the dyno is restarted your data disappears, and even if you have no intentions of restarting your dyno, Heroku maintenance may start new ones as hardware needs maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try gitignore?
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gitignore#ignoring_directories

Comment: That just means I don't send that folder to the server. It's already in my gitignore. But even when it's there, git push just removes everything that shouldn't be there